# Django Rest Framework - Add Data and return it

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django Rest Framework and trying to create add data upon request and return the data after creating.

My URL is `path('quiz/<str:classId>/<str:subject>/<str:chapter>', CreateQuiz.as_view()),`

I want to add a row to Quiz Model using the parameters in the URL and return it.
How should I approach this ? I tried adding it in get_queryset method and it runs twice. Any guide to this specific problem ? Please help.

**Serializer**:

```
class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    #get_questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields=(
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
            'url',
            'category',
            #'sub_category', 
            'random_order',
            'pass_mark',
            'draft',
            'durationtest',
            #'get_questions',
            #'get_max_score',
            #'questionlist',
            
        )
```

**View**:

```
class CreateQuiz(generics.ListCreateAPIView):    
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer
            
    def get_queryset(self):    
        classId = self.kwargs.get('classId',None)
        subject = self.kwargs.get('subject',None)
        category = Category.objects.filter(class_id=classId,category=subject).values_list('id',flat=True)[0]        
        # chapter = self.kwargs.get('chapter',None)
        
        subcategory=self.kwargs.get('chapter',None)
        subcat = SubCategory.objects.filter(id=subcategory).values_list('sub_category',flat=True)[0]
        total_marks = 30
        questionIDs = Question.objects.raw('''somesql
                                         ''',params=[category,subcategory,total_marks,category,subcategory,total_marks])
        #
        
        # and qq.sub_category_id IN %s
        questions= MCQuestion.objects.filter(question_ptr_id__in=questionIDs).prefetch_related('answer_set__question')
        essayquestions= Essay_Question.objects.filter(question_ptr_id__in=questionIDs)
        
        user = User.objects.get(id=1)
        
        if MCQuestion.objects.filter(question_ptr_id__in=questionIDs).prefetch_related('answer_set__question').exists():
                    print("create quiz")
                    
                    quiz = Quiz()
                    
                    quiz.category_id = category
                    quiz.title = "Practice"
                    quiz.owner= user
                    quiz.single_attempt = False
                    quiz.durationtest="10:00"
                    quiz.random_order=True
                    quiz.save()
                    
                    
                    quizid = Quiz.objects.filter(id=quiz.id).values_list('id',flat=True)[0]      
                    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(id=quiz.id)
                    quiz.title = "Practice Exam : "+ quiz.category.class_id.classVal +" "+quiz.category.category +" ("+subcat+") "
                    quiz.save()
                     
                    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO quiz_subcategory_quiz(subcategory_id,quiz_id) VALUES (%s,%s)",(subcategory,quiz.id,))
                    for obj in questionIDs:                           
                         
                        
                        if Question.objects.filter(id=obj.id,quiz__id=quiz.id).exists():
                            print("Do nothing")
                        else:
                            question = Question(id=obj.id)                        
                            question.quiz.add(quiz.id)
                            question.save()
                       
                    obj, created = UserQuiz.objects.update_or_create(
                            user_id = user.id,quiz_id=quiz.id            
                        )
                                        
                    return Quiz.objects.filter(id=quizid)
        else:
            response = JsonResponse({"error": "there was an error"})
            response.status_code = 403 # To announce that the user isn't allowed to publish
            return response    
                       
        return Quiz.objects.filter(id=quizid)
```

**Model**:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Title"),
        max_length=300, blank=False)

    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_("Description"),
        blank=True, help_text=_("a description of the quiz"))

    url = models.SlugField(
        max_length=60, blank=False,
        help_text=_("a user friendly url"),
        verbose_name=_("user friendly url"),default=uuid.uuid4)

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("Category"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    
    
    random_order = models.BooleanField(
        blank=False, default=False,
        verbose_name=_("Random Order"),
        help_text=_("Display the questions in "
                    "a random order or as they "
                    "are set?"))

    max_questions = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("Max Questions"),
        help_text=_("Number of questions to be answered on each attempt."))

    answers_at_end = models.BooleanField(
        blank=False, default=False,
        help_text=_("Correct answer is NOT shown after question."
                    " Answers displayed at the end."),
        verbose_name=_("Answers at end"))

    exam_paper = models.BooleanField(
        blank=False, default=True,
        help_text=_("If yes, the result of each"
                    " attempt by a user will be"
                    " stored. Necessary for marking."),
        verbose_name=_("Exam Paper"))

    single_attempt = models.BooleanField(
        blank=False, default=False,
        help_text=_("If yes, only one attempt by"
                    " a user will be permitted."
                    " Non users cannot sit this exam."),
        verbose_name=_("Single Attempt"))

    pass_mark = models.SmallIntegerField(
        blank=True, default=0,
        verbose_name=_("Pass Mark"),
        help_text=_("Percentage required to pass exam."),
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)])

    success_text = models.TextField(
        blank=True, help_text=_("Displayed if user passes."),
        verbose_name=_("Success Text"))

    fail_text = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_("Fail Text"),
        blank=True, help_text=_("Displayed if user fails."))

    draft = models.BooleanField(
        blank=True, default=False,
        verbose_name=_("Draft"),
        help_text=_("If yes, the quiz is not displayed"
                    " in the quiz list and can only be"
                    " taken by users who can edit"
                    " quizzes."))
    
    DIFFICULTY_LEVEL=[
        ('1','Beginner'),
        ('2','Intermediate'),
        ('3','Advanced'),
        ('4','Exppert'),
    ]

    difficulty = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=DIFFICULTY_LEVEL,
        default=2,
    )
    
    durationtest = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=True,null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,  null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True,null=True,)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Comment: Show what you've already tried. (serializer, model, view)

Comment: I have added all 3 , please suggest

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of confusion in what you're trying to achieve. The `get_queryset` method is meant to filter the data you want to send. In your case, it will just indicate which Quizz instances will be sent when you send a GET request (list).

Now, for what you want to do, sending a POST request and creating an instance from the URL parameters is absolutely not recommended. You must send information via the data part of your request. Anyway, in both cases you need to override the create method of your view.

```py
class CreateQuiz(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer
            
    def get_queryset(self):
    # return a queryset here, but don't create anything !

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # your logic resulting in having a variable your_data
        serializer = QuizSerializer(data=your_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            # return the data of your new instance here)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to create an instance using the parameter and send the latest instance back. I am trying to create a mobile app and need the API for that purpose. The user would select the parameters and send the request and API will send the instance back. Please let me know if there is still confusion. using "get_queryset" is incorrect , but nothing else seems to work coherently.